# Regex - match a word and capture that word

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I have the following code in a HTML page:

```
src="/images/picture1.gif"  ONMOUSEOVER="itempopup(event,'69168298'
src="/images/picture2.gif"  ONMOUSEOVER="itempopup(event,'69168223'
src="/images/picture3.gif"  ONMOUSEOVER="itempopup(event,'69168243'
src="/images/picture4.gif"  ONMOUSEOVER="itempopup(event,'69168249'
src="/images/pic1.gif"  ONMOUSEOVER="itempopup(event,'69168249'
src="/images/pictures10.gif"  ONMOUSEOVER="itempopup(event,'69168249'
```

and I want to build a Map with words of gifs that have picture+number -> {picture1=69168298, picture2=69168223 ...}
I've tried to capture the word picture+number but I didn't found the right combination.
Examples: ^(picture.)+$  , ^((picture).)+$, ^(?'picture'.)$. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your limiting the string using the `^$` characters. Just do it as follows:

`(pic(ture)?s?\d+).*?event,'(\d+)'`

And the `\1` and `\3` captured groups will contain the picture name and event id respectively

## Demo

The regex above will *also* match cases in your example such as `pic1` and `pictures10`, and even `pics123`

Comment: so, we both are 8k now

Comment: @AmitJoki, Looking at your rep. Not for long ;)

Answer (score 1):

With something like this :

```
/(picture[0-9]+).*'([0-9]+)'/
```

you will capture "picture1" and "69168298"

Comment: Just make sure not to have the `DOTALL` modifier enabled or this would match `picture1` and `69168249` (as `.*` is greedy and will match as much as possible).

Answer (score 1):

/(pic.*).gif.*\'(\d+)/gi could work possibly.